# Locating the source of a npm production build problem (Vue.js/Laravel-mix)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I can no longer get my production build to complete - I get an error message of the form:

`CssSyntaxError: D:\bruce\Documents\web\vietnam\dist\app.css:11653:22: Unknown word`

Other posted solutions to the `unknown word`-type error have focussed on errant characters in style blocks, so I removed all the style blocks from my .vue files and stopped Vuetify from being loaded.  The problem persisted.

I can't determine what character exists at position `11653:22` because `app.css` doesn't exist!

The dev build is working perfectly.

My vue.config.js file is:

```
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true,  
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
      })
    ],
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
          data: `@import "~@/sass/main.scss"`,
        },
      },
    },

    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [{
          loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "sass-loader",
          options: {
              implementation: require("sass"),
              fiber: require('fibers')
          }
        },
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        "css-loader",
        "sass-loader"
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    },
  ],
  },
};
```

My webpack.mix.js (production) is:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'dist/').sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'dist/');
```

My node version is 12.13.0 and npm version is 6.13.0. Webpack version 4.41.2 and webpack-cli version 3.3.10 are in use.

I'm unsure of what to try next to identify the source of my fault.

Comment: Is this of help: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2088

Comment: Yes, thanks, it was. I was using dynamic imports and so I focussed on this aspect of my code, and a couple of updates and tweaks later, it's all good - back to compiling successfully.  Thanks. Tom